# Corrupt contents in NodeJS ref-struct upon garbage collection

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, ref, ref-struct

Nesting a `ref-struct` instance within another, one of the properties of the nested object is corrupted upon manual garbage collection.

See this minimal code reproduction: https://github.com/hunterlester/minimum-ref-struct-corruption

Notice on the 3rd line of log output that the value of `name` is not corrupted:

```
Running garbage collection...
authGranted object afte gc:  { name: '�_n9a\u0002', 'ref.buffer': <Buffer@0x00000261396F3910 18 86 6c 39 61 02 00 00> }
Unnested access container entry after gc:  { name: 'apps/net.maidsafe.examples.mailtutorial', 'ref.buffer': <Buffer@0x00000261396F3B10 60 68 6e 39 61 02 00 00> }
Globally assigned values after gc:  apps/net.maidsafe.examples.mailtutorial  _publicNames
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'll provide a small reproducible piece of code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @vsenko Thank you for the suggestion, I've added a minimal example to the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `ref`, `ref-struct` and `ref-array` are powerful, but fragile things, their combination can behave really obscure.

There are two nuances with your sample:

1. Calling `makeAccessContainerEntry` twice overwrites your global cache - `CStrings` [cached](https://github.com/hunterlester/minimum-ref-struct-corruption/blob/master/index.js#L31) (`global.x0` and `global.x1`) during the `makeAuthGrantedFfiStruct` call will be overwritten by the second  direct[`makeAccessContainerEntry` call](https://github.com/hunterlester/minimum-ref-struct-corruption/blob/master/index.js#L48).
2. It seems that you should cache each `ContainerInfoArray` too.

This code should work fine:

```
const ArrayType = require('ref-array');
const ref = require('ref');
const Struct = require('ref-struct');
const CString = ref.types.CString;

const ContainerInfo = Struct({
  name: CString
});

const ContainerInfoArray = new ArrayType(ContainerInfo);

const AccessContainerEntry = Struct({
  containers: ref.refType(ContainerInfo)
});

const AuthGranted = Struct({
  access_container_entry: AccessContainerEntry
});

const accessContainerEntry = [
  {
    "name": "apps/net.maidsafe.examples.mailtutorial",
  },
  {
    "name": "_publicNames",
  }
];

const makeAccessContainerEntry = (accessContainerEntry) => {
  const accessContainerEntryCache = {
    containerInfoArrayCache: null,
    containerInfoCaches: [],
  };
  accessContainerEntryCache.containerInfoArrayCache = new ContainerInfoArray(accessContainerEntry.map((entry, index) => {
    const name = ref.allocCString(entry.name);
    accessContainerEntryCache.containerInfoCaches.push(name);
    return new ContainerInfo({ name });
  }));
  return {
    accessContainerEntry: new AccessContainerEntry({
      containers: accessContainerEntryCache.containerInfoArrayCache.buffer,
    }),
    accessContainerEntryCache,
  };
};

const makeAuthGrantedFfiStruct = () => {
  const ace = makeAccessContainerEntry(accessContainerEntry);
  return {
    authGranted: new AuthGranted({
      access_container_entry: ace.accessContainerEntry,
    }),
    authGrantedCache: ace.accessContainerEntryCache,
  };
}

const authGranted = makeAuthGrantedFfiStruct();
const unNestedContainerEntry = makeAccessContainerEntry(accessContainerEntry);

if(global.gc) {
  console.log('Running garbage collection...');
  global.gc();
}

console.log('authGranted object afte gc: ', authGranted.authGranted.access_container_entry.containers.deref());
console.log('Unnested access container entry after gc: ', unNestedContainerEntry.accessContainerEntry.containers.deref());
```

As you can see, I added cache to `makeAccessContainerEntry` output, you should keep it somewhere as long as you need the data to be held from garbage collection.

**Edit: some background**

JS implements high-level [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) where objects are referenced by references and memory gets released whenever there are no more references to the specific object.

In C there are no references and GC, but there are pointers which are simply memory addresses which point to the location where a specific structure or memory block is located.

`ref` uses the following technique to bind these two: C pointer is a Buffer which stores the memory address where the actual data is located in memory. Actual data is usually is represented as a Buffer too.

`ref-struct` is an addon to `ref` which implements the ability to interpret underlying memory blocks (Buffers) as structures - user defines types and how they are located in memory, `ref-struct` attempts to read the corresponding portion of a memory block and obtain the value.

`ref-array` is an addon to `ref` which implements the ability to interpret underlying memory blocks (Buffers) as arrays - user defines types and how they are located in memory, `ref-array` attempts to read the corresponding portion of a memory block and obtain the array item.

This way if you allocate a Buffer for something, then obtain a `ref` reference to it (a new Buffer that simply holds the memory address of the original Buffer) and lose the JS reference to the original Buffer, then the original Buffer could get released by GC like this:

```
function allocateData() {
  const someData = Buffer.from('sometext');
  return ref.ref(data);
}

const refReference = allocateData();
// There are no more direct JS references to someData - they are all left in the scope of allocateData() function.

console.log(refReference.deref());
global.gc(); // As long as there are no more JS references to someData, GC will release it and use its memory for something else.
console.log(refReference.deref());
```

Do not hurry to test this code - both `console.log(refReference.deref());` will print the same output because `ref` holds a hidden reference to the referenced `data` in the `refReference`.

`ref-struct` and `ref-array` are aware of such situations and usually correctly hold hidden references to the referenced data too. But a combination of `ref-struct` and `ref-array` reveals a bug or an underlying incompatibility and hidden references sometimes get lost. A workaround is to cache references by yourself - that is the approach I suggested to use.

Comment: Thank you @vsenko for taking the time to help me. This solution does prevent corrupted values upon garbage collection. I still wish I understood the bug more deeply but this is good for now.
Thank you.

Comment: @HunterLester, I added some background.